# UILocalnotification is not firing

Tags: objective-c

Since i just cant get a good answer for this and spend so much time on this, i will ask my question in details

All i want is to create an alarm according to date picker.
setting alarm to 10 seconds from now, is works great .
UIDatePicker, is works (print the date-but not the date i have picked, but 3 hours later)
i know there is an issue with local times, but i just cant find any good explanation.

my propose, and i guess that almost everyone,is not getting involve in local times, but to take each user's clock, and set alarm according to his time.

my code, is not working, i dont know why. its not firing(only if i set it to 10 seconds later)

please, i know that time zone should be different or something, but if you can explain what exactly to do and how, that would be great . thanks.

this is the code :

```
-(void)setDatePicker
{
    CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0,265,0,0);

    UIDatePicker *myPicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
    [myPicker addTarget:self action:@selector(pickerChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];


   [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] addSubview:myPicker];
     [myPicker release];
}



-(void)pickerChanged:(UIDatePicker*) datePicker
{


     date=datePicker.date;

     NSLog(@"value: %@",date);
}
```

and the local notification :

```
-(void) scheduleNotificationForDate: (NSDate*)theDate
{



/* Here we cancel all previously scheduled notifications */
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];


//NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init]autorelease];
//[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
//NSDate *notificationDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:theDate];


localNotification.fireDate = theDate;
NSLog(@"Notification will be shown on: %@",localNotification.fireDate);

localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
localNotification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                               @"Your notification message"];
localNotification.alertAction = NSLocalizedString(@"View details", nil);



localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = -1;

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got it .

i had to change the format and it worked.
nothing that relates to zones.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init]autorelease];
     [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
    NSDate *notificationDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateString];


    localNotification.fireDate = notificationDate;
```